# Getting pdf of X^2

Tags: probability-or-statistics

My goal is to get pdf of x^2 with x follows N(0,1).
I have tried as below but the result(at Out[41] is not what I expected(Sqrt[y] term supposed to be at denominator). How to correct?
(I have Copied nb file contents and pasted as below)

```
In[36]:= Clear[x, y, u, f]

In[37]:= f[x_] := (1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] ]) (E^((-x^2/2)))  

In[38]:= u[x_] := x^2

In[39]:= Solve[{u[x] == y}, x]

Out[39]= {{x -> -Sqrt[y]}, {x -> Sqrt[y]}}

In[40]:= \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-
\*SqrtBox[\(y\)]\), 
SqrtBox[\(y\)]]\(u[x]\ f[x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)

Out[40]= -E^(-y/2) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[y] + Erf[Sqrt[y]/Sqrt[2]]

In[41]:= D[-E^(-y/2) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[y] + Erf[Sqrt[y]/Sqrt[2]], y]

Out[41]= (E^(-y/2) Sqrt[y])/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `PDF[TransformedDistribution[x^2, Distributed[x, NormalDistribution[]]], x]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[x^2,
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]

(* ChiSquareDistribution[1] *)

CDF[dist, x]
```

[image]

```
PDF[dist, x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{CDF[dist, x], PDF[dist, x]}, {x, 0, 5},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.1},
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed["Expressions", {0.7, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Alternatively,

```
cdf[x_] = Probability[y^2 <= x, 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
```

[image]

This is an alternate form of the previous result for the CDF

```
cdf[x] == CDF[dist, x] // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

The PDF is then

```
pdf[x_] = cdf'[x]
```

[image]